# javaScript multiple time image not loading

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am drawing image which is loaded using loader method in two different places. But it only displays the second one. (I am following this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/)

If I add an alert() it works in Fx but not in Chrome. I want it to work everywhere without alert()

If I try drawing Image without using preloaded image I am getting the desired result. But I am thinking it is extra load (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

**ImageOnload("O",120,120); //This image not displaying**

**alert("If i add alert it works only in Fx but not in Chrome")**

**ImageOnload("O",120,20);//only this is displaying ???**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var ctx;
        var ImageVariable={};

        window.onload= function()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("gameLoop");   
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ImageBuilder(ImageSourceDB);
            ImageOnload("O",120,120); //This image is not displaying
                    //alert("If i add alert it works only in FFox but not in chrome")
            ImageOnload("O",120,20);  
        }

        var ImageSourceDB=
        {
            X:"./Images/X.gif",
            O:"./Images/O.gif"
        }
        function ImageBuilder(ImageSrcDB)
        {
            for (iSrc in ImageSrcDB)
            {
                ImageVariable[iSrc]= new Image();   
                    ImageVariable[iSrc].src = ImageSrcDB[iSrc];
            }
        }

        function ImageOnload(ImageSrc,x,y)
        {
            ImageVariable[ImageSrc].onload= function ()
            {
                ctx.drawImage(ImageVariable[ImageSrc],x,y);
            };          
                    ImageVariable[ImageSrc].src = ImageSourceDB[ImageSrc];
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <canvas class ="pattern" id="gameLoop" height="300"  width="300" />
    </body>
</html>
```

List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageOnload("O",120,120); //This image not displaying
ImageOnload("O",120,20);//only this is displaying ???
```

You forgot to change the id of the object:

```
ImageOnload("O",120,120);
ImageOnload("X",120,20); // Use "X", not "O"!!!
```

If you still want to show "O" twice, then you should draw it twice, but with only one `onload` function. See example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var ctx;
    var ImageVariable={};
    var ImageSourceDB = {
        X:"./Images/X.gif",
        O:"./Images/O.gif"
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("gameLoop");   
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ImageBuilder(ImageSourceDB);

        ImageVariable["O"].onload = function() {
            // this will be executed when the image "O" is loaded
            // this is a pointer to ImageVariable["O"]
            ctx.drawImage(this, 120, 120);
            ctx.drawImage(this, 120, 20);
        }
        ImageVariable["X"].onload = function() {
            // this will be executed when the image "X" is loaded
            ctx.drawImage(this, 30,  30);
        }
    }        
    function ImageBuilder(ImageSrcDB) {
        for (iSrc in ImageSrcDB) {
            ImageVariable[iSrc]= new Image();   
            ImageVariable[iSrc].src = ImageSrcDB[iSrc];
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying. I have not forgot the id, But I wanted to draw the same image two times, in different location.(Its one day late ..........hope I will get some help:) )

Comment: The thing is that you are trying to attach two different onload-actions for the same image in you ImageSourceDB. Why don't you just copy it first?

Comment: Hi John glad that your here :D. Can you help me with the code, I am very new in JavaScript and HTML5, Hope I am not asking too much :!

Comment: I will edit the answer. Hope as for the beginner it will help you. But I must say that you started with not an easy task to learn javascript.